# Changing line numbering format using algorithmic package

Tags: numbering, algorithms, algorithmic

The following code numbers each line in the algorithm as `<number><colon>`. Is there a way to number each line as `<number><period>`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm, algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{An algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE Input
\STATE A
\STATE B
\STATE C
\STATE D
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the line number delimiter using

```
\algsetup{
  linenodelimiter = {.}
}
```

Here is a visual of using a default and `.`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{An algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \REQUIRE Input
    \STATE A
    \STATE B
    \STATE C
    \STATE D
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

  \algsetup{
    linenodelimiter={.}
  }

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{An algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \REQUIRE Input
    \STATE A
    \STATE B
    \STATE C
    \STATE D
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```